# Nested AJAX call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm having trouble getting a nested AJAX call to work properly. All I want is to have the inner AJAX call executed if and after the outer AJAX call completed successfully.

```
var diningHours = $("#diningHours");
var facStaffDiningData = $("#facStaffDiningData");
var diningCommonsData = $("#diningCommonsData");
if($.trim(diningHours.html()).length == 0) {
    var season;
    //This call executes fine (tested it with console logging)
    $.get("data/dining-hours.php", {summer: "check"}, function(seasonData, seasonStatus) {
        if(seasonStatus == "success") {
            season = seasonData;
            //This is the call that isn't being executed
            $.get("data/dining-hours.php", function(hoursData, hoursStatus) {
                if(hoursStatus == "success") {
                    var hours = $(hoursData).find("hours dining");
                    var html = hoursFeed(hours, season);
                    diningHours.append(html).collapsibleset("refresh");
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's going on in Firebug? Are there any errors on the page?

Comment: It's a pretty good bet that `seasonStatus == "success"` is returning false, and why you would need to check if the status is "success" inside the success handler, is beyond me !

Comment: Is it that it's not executing, or is it that `$(hoursData).find("hours dining")` isn't selecting anything?  You might want to set some breakpoints and see exactly where the failure is.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Nope, no errors on the page.

Comment: @adeneo `seasonStatus` is returning "success". You're right, I had thought to check for "success" in case another status is returned but I now realize that I'm checking for that inside of the success callback. Thanks!

Comment: @MrOBrian It's not executing. I've put logging inside of the function and it seems like the callback is never even executed. I'll do some more digging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging deeper into the issue I found the true source of my problem. The XML document had a bunch of encoding errors (there were things like reserved and copyright symbols in with the data). Removing these and replacing them with the correct entities fixed the problem. My original code that I thought was the issue now works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think seasonStatus is redundant, because the callback will be executed on success.

This should works

```
var season;
    //This call executes fine (tested it with console logging)
    $.get("data/dining-hours.php", {summer: "check"}, function(season, seasonStatus) {
           console.log('CB1',season);
            $.get("data/dining-hours.php", function(hoursData) {
                    console.log('CB2',hoursData);
                    var hours = $(hoursData).find("hours dining");
                    var html = hoursFeed(hours, season);
                    diningHours.append(html).collapsibleset("refresh");

            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have had the extra status check. It still isn't working though.

Comment: Can you give us an example of seasonData ? maybe will we useful a console.log(seasonData) as a first line of callback function.

Comment: Sure, `seasonData` will either be "summer" or "fall". It's used as a variable in another function to determine how to traverse the XML document. Also, logging `seasonData` works fine inside of the callback of the first AJAX request (and returns the correct value). It's the callback of the second request that doesn't seem to be executing.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check CB2, if this log doesn't appear, the data/dining-hours.php is giving an http error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
var diningHours = $("#diningHours"),
    facStaffDiningData = $("#facStaffDiningData"),
    diningCommonsData = $("#diningCommonsData");

if(!$.trim(diningHours.html()).length) {
    var XHR = $.get("data/dining-hours.php", {summer: "check"});
        XHR.success(function(seasonData) {
            var season = seasonData,
                XHR2 = $.get("data/dining-hours.php");
                XHR2.success(function(hoursData) {
                    var hours = $(hoursData).find("hours dining"),
                        html = hoursFeed(hours, season);
                    diningHours.append(html).collapsibleset("refresh");
                });
        });
}​
```

The question is, what exactly is `hours dining`, and how do you expect the `find()` function to find it ?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. This code had worked fine before I decided to nest them so I know the `find()` method is working properly. I am using `find()` to traverse an XML file with those tags in it. Everything works properly without the AJAX calls being nested :(